# How to change language in MS Word table style

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, microsoft-word-2010, table-styles

How in this dialog can I get rid of the `Font: English (U.S.)` that is shown in the summary at the bottom?  I'm tired of changing the spell checking language for every table in a non-English document.

[image]

Comment: A workaround that might be of use is to create a new Table style and set it as the default table style. The new style shouldn't have an assigned language so it should default to the document language for spellchecking. Of course this will only help with newly added tables or ones you apply the new style to. A macro may also do the job: http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=89334#post293264

Answer (score 1):

- Open a document that has this problem. Press `Ctrl+A` to select all of the text
- Click on `Review` tab | Proofing: `Set Language` | < choose your language> | uncheck the "`Detect language automatically`" box
- Click on `Default` | Yes | OK.

[via](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?s=23df6a340cc321ab880767cddee7b061&p=13142583&postcount=4)

Comment: I'm reading the original question as that he does want to spell-check the table contents, just not in English. Your way would disable spell-checking altogether.

Comment: Indeed. I removed the "uncheck the 'Do not check spelling or grammar' box" instruction.

Comment: This solution is not chaning a style, just applying a spell checking language globally which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Table Grid and/or Table Normal styles ultimately are based on the Normal style. So if you change the language there (right-click the Normal style in the ribbon, and select Language), then that should take effect for tables too.

Comment: *Normal* is Czech, as is *Normal Table*.